# How to ignore type mismatch when using gson to parse input payload

Tags: java, gson

Class:

```
public class Site 
{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("switch_mgmt")
    Map<String, Object> switchMgmt;

}

String = "{" +
        " \"switch_mgmt\": \"\",\"id\": \"16fc48fa-5a5f-4b0b-882c-5347ef5e3969\"
        "}";
```

Here I am trying to use gson to parse the string above in the following way:

```
Site data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new Site().getClass());
```

But I keep getting the exception:

```
[redis] get /internal/sites redis exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 18 path $.switch_mgmt
```

I understand that there is a type mismatch which is why it's looking for a BEGIN_OBJECT but encountered a String. This payload is being set by the user through postman API and I have no control over the input given by the user.

Is there a way that gson can ignore this type mismatch?

Sample(ideal) example for switch_mgmt:

```
"switch_mgmt": {
    "proxy": false,
    "port": "2222",
    "root_password": "abc"
},
```

Comment: Can the `switch_mgmt` value be any JSON value, such as boolean or maybe even a non-empty string? If so, what parsed value do you expect in these cases? Or will it only ever be either an empty JSON string or a JSON object? Also, can't the user just fix the payload they are sending? If you are the one who provides this service which consumes the data, you should be the one who defines the structure of the JSON data, and if the user provides malformed JSON it would normally be their fault and not something you have to account for.

Comment: switch_mgmt is used throughout the code only as a map. Example:(Updated the ticket with a sample value). But the user is able to pass a "" when performing a PUT using the API(directly Via postman). Yes, we have given sample examples for the users to view and use and have also mentioned its type but the users rarely see documentations.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) which obtains the default adapter for the type of the field, but wraps it and first checks the JSON data to detect invalid values, such as an empty string in your example.
For example:

```java
class SwitchMgmtAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    // Constructor called by Gson using reflection
    public SwitchMgmtAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // Obtain the default adapter for the type of the field
        // Uses getAdapter instead of getDelegateAdapter due to https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1028
        TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getAdapter(type);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
                    return delegate.read(in);
                }

                // Otherwise handle malformed value
                // In this example here the value is skipped and `null` is returned,
                // but could instead also inspect the JSON value and use it in some way
                in.skipValue();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can then register that adapter factory on the field using [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html):

```java
public class Site 
{
    @JsonAdapter(SwitchMgmtAdapterFactory.class)
    @SerializedName("switch_mgmt")
    Map<String, Object> switchMgmt;

    ...
}
```

However, as mentioned in the comments personally I think it would be better to require that the client provides valid data. That makes it easier for you to maintain the code, and also easier for the client to notice that the data they are sending is malformed. Otherwise they might waste hours trying to understand why the value they provided is ignored.
Though also note that Gson currently [does not detect unknown fields](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/188) and [missing fields](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/61).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to create a deserializer class which was then used by gson typeadapter based on your answer.